# Authentication not going through after successful login in Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, authentication, xamarin.android, adal

I have an app using ADAL to authenticate the user. After pressing the login button, the sign in page shows up but after entering the right credentials nothing happens. I've checked all the variables needed for authentication (common authority, redirect uri, client ID) and it still comes out

Here's the authentication part;

```
private async Task<bool> AuthenticateUsingADAL(IPlatformParameters parent)
{
    var success = false;
    try
    {
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(CommonAuthority);
        if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Count() > 0)
            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);
        AuthResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceUri, ClientId, RedirectUri, parent);
        //i put a WriteLine here but nothing goes through after the AuthResult. I don't know why

        success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Authentication failed " + ex.ToString());
    }
    return success;
}
```

The login activity:

```
public bool Login(Activity activity)
{
    bool result = false;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Token) || TokenExpired) result = AuthenticateUsingADAL(new PlatformParameters(activity)).Result;

    return result;
}
```

Which is started by this:

```
private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool success = false;

    Task loginTask = new Task(() =>
    {
        success = SessionsHelper.Login(this);
    });

    loginTask.ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (success) GoToNextActivity();
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    loginTask.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to read the things from cache . Change your code like follows ,

```
var authContext = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext(authority);  
 authContext.tokenCache.readItems().then(function (items) {
 if (items.length > 0) {
        authority = items[0].authority;
        authContext = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext(authority);
 }
 // Attempt to authorize user silently
 authContext.acquireTokenSilentAsync(resourceUri, clientId)
 .then(authCompletedCallback, function () {
    // We require user cridentials so triggers authentication dialog
    authContext.acquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientId, redirectUri)
    .then(authCompletedCallback, errorCallback);
  });
});
```